# Bootstrap grid with different image heights

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I'm working on a dynamic album art grid with CSS and Bootstrap 3 and everything works fine, when all images are scaled 1:1. But when an image occurs that is not scaled like that, my grid breaks. Here is a screenshot of my problem:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DogkO.jpg)

[But what I want is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZcSQ.jpg)

The code to generate the grid looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 panel panel-default" v-for="result in results">
        <img src="{{ result.art }}" />
        <strong>{{ result.title }}</strong>
        <br />
        from <strong>{{ result.album }}</strong>
        <br />
        by <strong>{{ result.artist }}</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Vue.js for this template.

So I can't place such two col-md-6 into one row, but when I chain the columns the grid is breaking.

Is there any way to get a correct grid with these kind of images? I don't need something like masonry-style, just a regular bootstrap grid.

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: have you tried `<div class="clearfix">` after each `col-md-6` ?

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: @M.Tanzil method will work as well and you can do this with :before / :after pseudo class with nth-child selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add something every 2 `col-md-6` to ensure the left floats clear..

One way is to use [Bootstrap's clearfix reset](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets), another way is to use a CSS reset like this..

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .row > .col-md-6:nth-child(2n+1) {
        clear: left;
    }
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/oAiZNlWgau

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to achieve this.

Wrap each row into it's own row

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6>Content</div>
<div class="col-md-6>Content</div>
</div>
```

You can also set a min-height for each item, that way they will always be the same height.

Lastly, you can not use the bootstrap grid system and build your own grid by using display: inline-block; just be sure to set negative margin on each element and v-align to top.

Hope this helps :P